# Refresh Active Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, database, powerquery

I am reading data from a database via excel power query.  I would like to create a refresh button so I dont have to continue to go to the data tab then select refresh or refresh all.  There are times I want to only refresh a worksheet and other times workbook.

The code is driven off a single cell value that is manually entered. I have to refresh for two reasons.  First, to pull in the data from multiple tables in the data base.  Second, as changes are being made, I need to update the worksheet based on the changes being made to the data as we are using the worksheet to view the data.

I have tried a slew of simple codes to accomplish this but it will not work.

```vb
Private Sub refreshSheet_Click()
    ActiveSheet.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`